# why in Action and Parameters IS LIST is automatically checked for some Parameter Name?

Tags: dialogflow-es

When I am calling the dialogflow from API in Action and Parameters section 
ISLIST is automatically coming checked for one of my ParameterName because of which I am getting a blank response.
Why ISLIST is automatically getting checked?
[check the screenshot of the ISLIST automatically checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pniXQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you have entered the parameters more than once in a training phrase and matched the same parameter, it may have caused it.

I can't see the image you shared. So, I answered the question according to my estimates. If I'm wrong, please let me know, I'd be happy to help you.

Comment: Yes, this is the right. I received the mail from the dialog-flow team their answer is exactly same.